# Laravelでキューでメール送信するとURLが変わってしまう

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.1でメール本文にURLを記載して送信しています。
メールをキュー使わずに送信した時と、キューを使って送信した時で、メール本文のURLが変わってしまいます。どの様にしたら修正できるでしょうか？

テストは`php artisan serve`で実行しているので、URLは`http://localhost:8000`です。

#### メール送信

```
private function sendConfirmMail(Mailer $mailer, User $user)
{
    // $mailer->send(
    $mailer->queue(    // <--ここをキューに変更した
        'emails.confirm',
        ['user' => $user, 'token' => $user->confirmation_token],
        function($message) use ($user) {
            $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('ユーザー登録確認');
        }
    );
}
```

#### メールビュー: emails.confirm

```
<p>
    ようこそ、{{ $user['name'] }} さん
</p>

<p>
    以下のリンクをクリックしてユーザーを有効化してください。
</p>

<p>
    <a href="{{ url('auth/confirm', [$token]) }}">ユーザーを有効化する</a>
</p>

<p>
    {{ url('auth/confirm', [$token]) }}
</p>
```

#### 届いたメール：$mail->send()の時

```
ようこそ、Hoge さん

以下のリンクをクリックしてユーザーを有効化してください。

ユーザーを有効化する

http://localhost:8000/auth/confirm/d1533d919888227a3b2a48a4ed483686bcb19a45ad3b9c46e4c1f0c144dde269
```

URLは正しく`http://localhost:8000`と表示されている

#### 届いたメール：$mail->queue()の時

```
ようこそ、Hoge さん

以下のリンクをクリックしてユーザーを有効化してください。

ユーザーを有効化する

http://localhost/auth/confirm/d1533d919888227a3b2a48a4ed483686bcb19a45ad3b9c46e4c1f0c144dde269
```

URLが何故か`http://localhost`と表示される

Answer (score 3, accepted):

config/app.phpのurlを変更すれば直ります。
このurlはartisanコマンドラインアプリ内でurlを生成する時に使用されます。

キューは`artisan queue:listen`もしくは`artisan queue:work`で処理されるので、urlを生成するurl()を使った時に、ここで設定したurlを使用します。

キューで無い時は、実際にリクエストを受けたサーバのurlが使用されます。

```
// config/app.php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This URL is used by the console to properly generate URLs when using
| the Artisan command line tool. You should set this to the root of
| your application so that it is used when running Artisan tasks.
|
*/

'url' => 'http://localhost:8000',
```